# Getting error while processing print from custom processing screen

Tags: acumatica

I have created a Processing screen, To process EMAIL and PRINT of multiple Payment and Application documents.

While Processing PRINT I am getting the following ERROR.
[enter image description here][1]

The Screen ID showing in the error message is the report screen ID which should pop up to print the report. but the Report is not popping up.

[enter image description here][2]

We are getting error in line no 72, throw ex;

I am unable to find out where I am going wrong,

Thanks In Advance.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZbKN.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1oLj.png

Please refer image for more clarification...

Comment: Please do not post images of code. Code is TEXT, and this site has excellent markdown support for displaying text. Also note that ALL UPPERCASE is considered yelling in the internet, and you don't want to create the impression of yelling at the people you ask to help you.

Comment: I suggest you edit that code into the question as requested and then take some stesp to find out a specific error message for the line that the error is occuring on

Comment: Line 72 is not the throw.  It is ex.SeparateWindows = true.  Can you provide the trace?  There are a lot of examples using PXReportRequiredException.CombineReport in the code repository, but the one I found uses NotificationUtility(this).SearchReport to get the report ID.  I wonder if you are missing a setup step for the report or if the screen ID is in another format (i.e. AR.30.20.70)

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to the code to find out more information

```
if (ex!=null)
{..}
else
{
   PXTrace.WriteError(ex);
   throw new PXException(ex.Message);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the code snippet you showed is of ARPaymentEntry graph extension however you also mention that it is a custom processing screen. If you have added this action to the Payments screen, then try the below code snippet. You could use one of the overrides of PXReportRequiredException method as needed.

```
public PXAction<PX.Objects.AR.ARPayment> PrintReceipt;

        [PXButton(CommitChanges = true)]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Print Official Receipt")]
        protected IEnumerable printReceipt(PXAdapter adapter)
        {
            Base.Save.Press();
            string reportID = "AR302070";
            List<ARPayment> list = adapter.Get<ARPayment>().ToList();
            int i = 0;
            Dictionary<string, string> parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            foreach (ARPayment payment in list)
            {
                parameters["PaymentType"] = payment.DocType;
                parameters["PaymentNbr"] = payment.RefNbr;

                i++;
            }
            if (i > 0)
            {
                throw new PXReportRequiredException(parameters, reportID, string.Format("Report {0}", reportID));
            }
            return list;
        }
```